# Flood fill for multiple files

Tags: image, image-processing, batch-file, bitmap

I have several hundred bitmap files for which I'd like to do a flood fill to change one of the colors.  Are there any programs out there that will allow me to do this, or which will allow me to write a script to do this sort of processing?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

take a look at **graphicsmagick** http://www.graphicsmagick.org/

and use something like this

```
 for %%f in (*.bmp) do (
   gm convert -draw "fill yellow ; color 0,0 floodfill" %%f %%~nf.new.bmp
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've downloaded the program and will give it a try.